# how to use a PHP Constant that gets pulled from a database

Tags: php, constants

Can you read out the name of a PHP constant from a database and use it inside of a php variable, to display the value of the constant for use in a menu?

For example here's what I'm trying to accomplish

In SQL: `select menu_name AS php_CONSTANT where menu_id=1` the value returned would be L_HOME which is the name of a CONSTANT in a php config page.  The php config page looks like this `define('L_HOME','Home');` and gets loaded before the database call.
The php usage would be `$db_returned_constant` which has a value of `L_HOME` that came from the db call,  then I would place this into a string such as `$string = '<ul><li>' . $db_returned_constant . '</li></ul>'` and thus return a string that looks like `$string = '<ul><li><a href="#" onclick="path_from_db">Home</a></li></ul>'`.

To sum up what I'm trying to do

1. Load a config file based on the language preference
2. query the db to return the menu name, which is the name of a CONSTANT in the config file loaded in step one, and also retrieve the menu_link which is used in the  "onclick" event.
3. Use a php variable to hold the name of the CONSTANT
4. Place the variable into a string that gets echo'd out to create the menu displaying the value of the CONSTANT.

I hope this makes enough sense...is it even possible to use a constant like this?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be because it's late already but I don't understand this at all, sorry :) if you want to inject the constant into the query you can use `"SELECT menu_name AS ".constant("php_CONSTANT")." where....."` ... not sure whether that fully answers your question though.

Comment: I'm also having a problem understanding.

Can you narrow down the specific part you're having problems with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define('L_HOME','Home');
$db_returned_constant = 'L_HOME'; // value actually retrieved from db
echo constant($db_returned_constant);

// will output 'Home'
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just retrieve the name of a constant into a string and then use `constant`.